# Timezone Issue with DayJS React and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

In each record that I save to MongoDB, I execute it with Date.noe, example:

```
   createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
```

So in mongoDB I have the record saved as follows:

```
createdAt: 2023-02-01T01:39:03.377+00:00
```

In React I get the records and in this way I show the date using DayJS:

```
dayjs(createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY')
```

But the problem is that the date indicates that the registration was made on **02-2023-01** but when using DayJS the date changes to **01-31-2023**

Changing the day decreases the record by one day and this is causing me conflicts since they are about financial records.

On my server I don't have any time stamp, I use MongoDB from Atlas (cloud.mongodb)

This is my query to mongoDB where when requesting the information for the month of February, it correctly returns this, but in React if the record is from February 1, 2023, it shows me February 31, 2023:

```
db.purchases.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "detail.category._id": ObjectId("63bf4d0b10dfcae061b6eab0")
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$detail"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$detail.category._id",
            total: { $sum: "$total" },
            totalProductPurchases: { $sum: "$detail.quantity" },
            purchasesCount: { $sum: 1 },
            purchases: {
                $push: {
                    $cond: [
                        {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: [{ $year: "$createdAt" }, 2023] },
                                { $eq: [{ $month: "$createdAt" }, 2] },
                                { $gte: [{ $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" }, 1] },
                                { $lte: [{ $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" }, 31] }
                            ]
                        },
                        { 
                            purchaseId: "$_id",
                            month: { $month: "$createdAt" },
                            isoWeek: { $isoDayOfWeek: "$createdAt" },
                            dayOfMonth: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" }, 
                            createdAt: "$createdAt",
                            total: "$total",
                            subtotal: "$subtotal",
                            tax: "$tax",
                            discount: "$discount",
                            totalBeforeTax: "$totalBeforeTax",
                            createdAt: "$createdAt",
                            paymentType: "$paymentType"
                        },
                        false 
                    ]
                }
            },
             product_counts: { 
                $push: {
                    product: "$detail.name",
                    count: "$detail.quantity"
                }            },
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$product_counts"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$product_counts.product",
            ProductPurchasesNumber: { $sum: "$product_counts.count" },
            purchases: { $first: "$purchases"},
            totalProductPurchases: { $first: "$totalProductPurchases"},
            total: { $first: "$total"},
            purchasesCount: { $first: "$purchasesCount"}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { count: -1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 3
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            top3Products: { $push: { product: "$_id", ProductPurchasesNumber: "$ProductPurchasesNumber" } },
            total: { $first: "$total" },
            totalProductPurchases: { $first: "$totalProductPurchases" },
            purchasesCount: { $first: "$purchasesCount" },
            purchases: { $first: "$purchases" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            purchasesArrayLength: { $size: "$purchases" },
            filteredPurchases: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$purchases",
                    as: "purchase",
                    cond: { $ne: [ "$$purchase", false ] }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            purchases: 0
        }
    } 
])
```

How can I avoid these kinds of errors? Thank you.

Comment: The date saved is represented by a UTC date (at least in whatever way you're viewing it). When that is displayed locally, it is converted to the local timezone. They both still represent the same instance in time so it's not clear what the problem is

Comment: @Phil The problem is that the record is created on 02-2023-01 and it is correct, but when I do a search by date looking for records from the month of February, it actually gives me the record but in React using dayJS instead of showing the date 02/01/2023 shows me 31/01/2023 using dayjs(createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY')

Comment: As Phil said it's because the UTC date is being localized. If you want to impose a certain timezone you can specify timezone using DayJS. From their example: 
dayjs.tz("2013-11-18 11:55:20", "America/Toronto")

Comment: Sounds like the date you're sending in the search criteria is UTC instead of local. It's impossible to help further without more information on how these dates are constructed and passed between client and server

Comment: In short, if you query for records matching an UTC date criteria, don't be surprised if those dates don't align with your localised expectations

Comment: @Phil So what format do you save the dates in? Some time ago I was told to use UTC without additional formatting but now I have these problems.

Comment: It's not about the persisted format, it's about the value of your search criteria. If you want records matching a local date range, send local dates for the query, not UTC. And again, without seeing your code, I cannot offer anything else

Comment: In the documentation they are telling that UTC should not have fraction second. https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format . Your timestamp  has :03.377 second .

Comment: @Phil I have added the query to MongoDB where I get the data for example from the record of February 2, 2023 but React shows it as Jan 31, 2023

Comment: @ManojBhat I don't understand then, I recently asked the same thing and they told me not to change anything when saving dates but now I have these complications

Comment: You're searching by server-side date, and probably in UTC. Pass the date range you want to query from your client-side. Otherwise you will always get dates matching your server-side / UTC criteria

Comment: @Phil Ok entonces lo intentaré enviando las fechas, gracias

Comment: @JasonLong I was looking for a lot of info and changing my query in Mongo but in the end you were right, setting the time zone in DayJS now works fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to retrieve records matching dates in the client-side timezone, send the dates in the API call.

For example, on the React side

```js
// These will be local date instances
const startDate = new Date(2023, 1, 1); // Start of day Feb 1st
const endDate = new Date(2023, 2, 1, 0, 0, -1); // End of day Feb 28

const params = new URLSearchParams({
  startDate: startDate.toISOString(),
  endDate: endDate.toISOString(),
});

fetch(`/api/purchases?${params}`)
  .then(...);
```

and on the server-side, parse the dates from the query string and use them in your MongoDB aggregate query

```js
const startDate = new Date(req.query.startDate);
const endDate = new Date(req.query.endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements and questions are not really clear to me, but I would write the conditions like this:

```
{
   $cond: [
      {
         $eq: [
            { $dateTrunc: { date: "$createdAt", unit: 'month', timezone: 'America/New_York' } },
            DateTime.local({ zone: "America/New_York" }).startOf('month').toJSDate()
         ]
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

or

```
{
   $cond: [
      {
         $and: [
            { $gte: ["$createdAt", DateTime.local({ zone: "America/New_York" }).startOf('month').toJSDate()] },
            { $lte: ["$createdAt", DateTime.local({ zone: "America/New_York" }).endOf('month').toJSDate()] }
         ]
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

I prefer [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) over `Day.js`, I think the same function are also available in Day.js.